# Redirect to local network without allow_localnet

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I'd like to redirect incoming external traffic to a service which listens on 127.0.0.1. The redirection is easy - just:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING \
    -d local_ip --dport 80 \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:port
```

but this leaves the packet on `eth0` and it's just logged as martian and dropped by default. I can enable `route_localnet` on `eth0` to fix this, but that exposes the whole interface to weird routing tricks.

How do I forward it correctly without `route_localnet`?

Comment: If you really cannot reconfigure the service to listen on eth0... Not sure if it's gonna work (cannot check it right now), but I'd try with DNAT instead of REDIRECT. The last resort option is to use SSH tunnel internally.

Comment: DNAT gives the same result (i.e. packet doesn't change the interface and gets logged as martian on eth0)

Answer (score 1):

The *correct* way to handle this is to have the application listen on the correct interface and/or IP address, not 127.0.0.1, and use iptables only to allow traffic, not to play weird NAT tricks.

Comment: Sure it's true, but that wasn't the question :)

Comment: @viraptor It looks like the question to me. You've shown no good reason why you should need to do something bizarre and difficult to manage like this, so we can only surmise that you're trying to "do it wrong", whatever it is.

Comment: Sample scenario: application binds to one interface/address and doesn't support 0.0.0.0. Provide access from 2 different interfaces even though it binds to one only.